# XCode automatically deactivating breakpoints

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I'm using xcode in C++. I'm trying to debug my project, but at random intervals, it seems to ignore my breakpoints. There are three things that it does:

1) Sometimes, when I run, it automatically switches to "de-activate break points" mode. (the relevant button goes light and says "Activate")

2) Sometimes when I run, ALL of my breakpoints go "can't find" mode, with the yellow insides. I need to click twice on them to get them back dark blue (once to light blue = inactive, once to dark blue = active)

3) Sometimes, when I run, my breakpoint is dark blue, the button says "deactivate" and it still just ignores my breakpoint, running straight past it.

This makes it very difficult to debug my program...

I should add that I'm using XCode 3.1 beta on OSX 10.5.6, in case that matters.

thanks.

Comment: Upvoting, since I've experienced exactly the same - in fact, compared to VS, I'm completely clueless as to how breakpoints work in XCode. I expected similar behavior to VS but alas, it was not meant to be.

Comment: I've seen this while trying to debug iPhone apps.  Very annoying.

Comment: I've also posted this to the apple discussion boards. If I get an answer there, I'll repost it here.

Also, I'm very familiar with gdb, the command line part, but it doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try unchecking the **Load symbols lazy** in the **Debugging** panel in **Preferences**

Comment: Heh, you get credit for that here AND in apple forums... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem but only restarting the iPhone Simulator seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue right now.
I tried all the options : enabling the GCC, active, base targets and restarting and closing xcode, nothing solved.
I finally restarted the simulator and things have started working.

Answer (score 0):

I have more or less the same set of issues, and this suggestion of loading symbols lazily unfortunately does not resolve it for me.  Moreover, I am not developing for the iphone, just a regular application.

To be specific, sometimes I can't disable or enable breakpoints on the fly - sometimes my code doesn't stop in breakpoints which I later prove are being executed (with print statements) and nothing I can do will make it stop there - I see that very annoying debug symbol with an orange center, even though I only have one project active.

Quitting and restarting XCode occasionally has an effect - and annoyingly, there have been a very small number of cases where quitting and restarting or rebuilding from clean fixed hard-to-diagnose compilation/linking errors.  Unfortunately, I just tried all of these with no effect.

(Unrelated, my keyboard shortcuts are also unreliable.  My shortcut of F2 for continue worked for weeks for me, stopped working for a long time, was working this morning and now doesn't work at exactly the same breakpoint it worked before - yet my F1, step over, key has been completely reliable...)

I'm a little disappointed to have to do so much debugging with print statements!